# InstallShield Template Summary Value AMD64 vs Intel64 vs x64

Tags: cpu, processor, installshield-2012

I am setting up my InstallShield to install my package as 64 bit (into Program Files not Program Files x86) by.

My processor is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU

InstallShield  => General Information => Summary Information Stream => Template Summary
From `Intel32;1033` to `Intel64;1033`

And it gives me the general error message:

> This installation package is not supported by this processor

Then I set the value to:

```
Amd64;1033 or x64;1033
```

And it magically work.

But weird thing is, my processor is Intel, how come it work for Amd64? But not Intel64?

So..... I have been reading [this](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpTemplateSummary.htm) , [this](https://superuser.com/questions/383711/whats-the-difference-between-intel-64-and-amd64) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64).

Obviously Amd64 was referred as x86-64 or x86_64 or Amd64, the 64 bit version of x86-instruction set.

Then Intel take the IA and called it Intel64.

So, then.... why wouldn't my Intel Processor not work with Intel64 but with Amd64?

Answer (score 3):

The [platform token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372070.aspx) `Intel64` refers to the [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) architecture. Modern 64-bit processors from both AMD and Intel aren't Itanium; instead they are the architecture collectively known as [AMD64 or x64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). These two architectures are not related, so code for one will not run on the other.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... So platform token Intel64 is different from the Intel 64 they called for IA-32e or EM64T?  Is there a reference page the platform token Intel64 is refers to the Itanium architecture?